# Cannot change "Territory" in itunesconnect summary page

Tags: ios, app-store

I have designed an app to be run exclusively in India, but in the **Version Summary** page in **itunesconnect**, the **Territory** is set to **USA**. Even if I select **India**.

When I reload the page, it is switched back to **USA**. Save button does not appear here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your app from iTunes Connect. After that Go to Pricing and tap below  "specific territories" link . And choose your specific Territory and save. I have tested it works for me.